# App rejected for fetching user's location in background for Apple Watch app

Tags: core-location, background-process, apple-watch

We have introduced a Watch component in our iOS application. If a user launches the app on the Apple Watch, they will be able to see the timing for the next prayer, and the countdown to it, based on their current location.
The user should be able to view this information on the Watch even if the app on the phone is not launched. For this purpose, we need to use Background Location, to ensure we have the user’s current location at all times. The prayer timings are dependent on the user’s location.
Upon submitting this app on the Appstore, our application got rejected for the following reason:

Upon further review we found your application features do not require persistent location. Apps that declare support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features that require persistent location.

Please can you suggest me how can I fetch the user’s current location for Watch application when the iOS app is in the background without using UIBackgroundModes key for location services.

Comment: You can't just get the watches locale time? Not an Apple engineer but that could be a way to by-pass using GPS.

Comment: The prayer time we show is sent by the server. It is dependant on the user's location. That's why we need GPS.

Comment: Are you able to check if the iPhone version of the app is sent to the background, then save that time.